# Replacing the first two commas of a string

Tags: java, regex, string

Is there a regex that can be used for replacing only the two first commas in a String with another character?

The reason why I need this is that I am working with RDF triples, where I need to handle the subject, predicate and object separately. So I split them into three separate parts using the String.split() method.

This is an example of the Strings that I need to split:

[http://dbpedia.org/resource/Tom_Mathisen, http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment, "Tom Mathisen (born 14 August 1952) is a Norwegian comedian, actor, screenwriter and musician. He usually handles bass, guitar and vocals. He was in the comedy group Prima Vera from 1976 to 1983 along with Jahn Teigen and Herodes Falsk. Later he continued to work with Herodes Falsk on many TV/scene shows and records."@en]

For instance I want this String to look like this instead, so I can split using $:

[http://dbpedia.org/resource/Tom_Mathisen$ http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment$ "Tom Mathisen (born 14 August 1952) is a Norwegian comedian, actor, screenwriter and musician. He usually handles bass, guitar and vocals. He was in the comedy group Prima Vera from 1976 to 1983 along with Jahn Teigen and Herodes Falsk. Later he continued to work with Herodes Falsk on many TV/scene shows and records."@en]

I did it in a less elegant way:

```
StringBuilder stringbuilder = new StringBuilder(str);
int commaCounter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < stringbuilder.length(); i++) {
    if (stringbuilder.charAt(i) == ',') {
        stringbuilder.setCharAt(i, '$');
        commaCounter++;
        if (commaCounter == 2) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
str = stringbuilder.toString();
```

Comment: an example would be better. Is that splitting or replacing?

Comment: Not just better, example is absolutely essential in this question.

Comment: I have edited the question now. Hope it gives a bit more context for the readers.

Comment: So 1st 2 commas need to be removed OR need to replaced with something?

Comment: They need to be replaced with a different character.

Comment: Ok, show your expected output also in question.

Comment: @Jea after you replace first two `,` from `$`. will you split by `$`?

Comment: From now on I will always remember replaceFirst(",", "x");

Comment: @Jea Good. You want to split by `$` now?

Comment: @ruchiraGayanRanaweera Yes, but in the question I asked for a regex to replace a comma with a different character. Thank you for your answer though, it was nice to know so I gave it a +1.

Comment: @Jea Ok. you are welcome. But no need to replace `,` first two with some other and split by that later. Do it in once.

Comment: True, I ultimately ended up using your solution even if that was not what I asked for in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this is relatively straight forward?

```
String s = input.replaceFirst(",", "x").replaceFirst(",", "x");
```

Comment: +1 for avoiding regex. Jamie Zawinski: 'Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.'

Comment: Thanks. Not a regex, but a much nicer solution.

Comment: Ok, sorry. Even better ;)

Comment: @Jea - `String replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)` is the signature :P

Comment: Actually, it is a regex, but since `,` is not a special character, we get away with what looks like a normal string replace :)

Comment: @vikingsteve - quite true. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use two times `replaceFirst`. This will do what you want. Use a forloop if you want to replace an specific char the first `n` times.

```
    String s = "this, is, a, Test";
    int count = 2;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        s = s.replaceFirst(",", "");
    System.out.println(s);
```

Output:
`this is a, Test`

Or if you always want to replace only the first two chars you can chain the methods.

```
   String s = "this, is, a, Test";
   s = s.replaceFirst(",", "$").replaceFirst(",", "$");
```

Comment: Why for loop? just use replaveFirst twice

Comment: I like this solution. Its scalable.

Comment: Please always use curly brackets on a for-loop, even if it's only one line! Best practise...

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to replace the comma, you can call replaceFirst 2 times. For example:

```
    String someString = "a, b, c, d";
    someString = someString.replaceFirst(",", "-");
    someString = someString.replaceFirst(",", "-");

    System.out.println(someString);
```

Output is:

```
    a- b- c, d
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split your text from fist two `,` directly as follows. To split no need to replace `,` with `$`. That is overkill just split at once from first two `,`;

```
String str="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Tom_Mathisen, http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment, \"Tom Mathisen (born 14 August 1952) is a Norwegian comedian, actor, screenwriter and musician. He usually handles bass, guitar and vocals. He was in the comedy group Prima Vera from 1976 to 1983 along with Jahn Teigen and Herodes Falsk. Later he continued to work with Herodes Falsk on many TV/scene shows and records.\"@en";
String[] arr=str.split(",",3);
 for (String i : arr) {
        System.out.println(i);
 }
```

Out put:

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Tom_Mathisen
http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment
"Tom Mathisen (born 14 August 1952) is a Norwegian comedian, actor, screenwriter and musician. He usually handles bass, guitar and vocals. He was in the comedy group Prima Vera from 1976 to 1983 along with Jahn Teigen and Herodes Falsk. Later he continued to work with Herodes Falsk on many TV/scene shows and records."@en
```

Comment: @amitbhardwaj the ultimate goal of OP seems to be split from first two `,`

Comment: read comments below question you will understand the ultimate goal of OP

Comment: there is no need to put another answer as there are lot of right answer for what OP really want

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on regex,

```
System.out.println("a, b, c, d".replaceAll("^([^,]*),([^,]*),", "$1X$2X"));
```

Output:

```
aX bX c, d
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gS3iY5/9)